# Can't Edit HTML file in Webstorm 7

Tags: html, javascript, webstorm

I am new to Webstorm which is an Integrated Development (Programming) Environment (IDE). That is to say it is directly involved tool used primarily for programming. Specifically one programs JavaScript which is a popular language used by many programmers to enable rich web client functionality.

I opened a file I had been editing in Webstorm 6 and now I cannot edit the file.

This is the trial version.

I totally can't press almost all keys or alter the file, it is like it is locked. Backspace does work for some reason.

Am I missing something?

Am on OSX 10.8.5.